# Bathroom outlet tripping causes power loss in multiple areas

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, gfci

Is it normal that when my bathroom outlet randomly trips it shuts off power to my bathroom, staircase lights, and some outlets in my living room? I'm starting to get concerned I rent a apartment.

Comment: If it was done with older code, quite possible to have multiable outlets/lights one one circuit.  Newer code limits bathrooms and kitchens.

Comment: Is the tripping occuring when high current appliances are used in the bathroom or is the breaker tripping due to a ground fault?

Comment: Well if the bathroom outlet is tripping, the first task is to fix the appliance that is causing it to trip.  You seem to be looking for a workaround to prevent it affecting other rooms **when you keep on tripping it**, and that's really the wrong solution path here.

Comment: If you rent an apartment and are in the USA, call your landlord to have an electrician come fix the issue or advise as to how you can avoid it if there is no actual problem with the wiring/electrical system. It is illegal for you to do your own work as an apartment tenant or even as a landlord in the US.

Comment: How often is the circuit tripping? I doubt it trips "randomly". Maybe you mean unexpectedly or inconveniently or from no apparent cause . . . You COULD actually mean randomly, but as I say I doubt you mean that, or do you?

Comment: Do you have a GFCI breaker on this circuit or do you have a GFCI receptacle? If the latter, is the GFCI receptacle in the bathroom?

Comment: It's normal that the entire circuit trips off, but it's (AFAIK) not normal for a bathroom outlet that can easily trip off, to be on the same circuit as staircase lights that are really important so people don't fall down the stairs. I don't think that's allowed. They have to be on different circuits. It's ALSO not normal for ANYTHING to randomly trip.